Can't get a seekable File Stream with ContentResolve and Xamarin Android
I'm updating a Xamarin Android App to save TIFF images on an SD Card.
I'm using LibTIFF and there is a function that accept a Stream.
I have created the output file by calling DocumentFile.CreateFile and I got the stream by calling ContentResolver.OpenOutputStream, the issue is that the Stream is Output only and not seekeable.
The LibTIFF library is writing and reading from the stream, changing position, etc.. and these features seems not to be supported with the ContentResolver. Do you know any workaround?
Note: I can't use a MemoryStream because images sometimes are pretty large.
I tried to create a Stream class that wrap OpenOutputStream and OpenInputStream, but the issue is that OpenInputStream is not seekable anyway. Syncronization of the IN/OUT stream is another issue then.
SOLVED:
I managed to solve this by getting the Java Channel associated to the Stream and then calling Position() in a similar way to https://github.com/madnik7/PortableStorage/blob/master/PortableStorage.Android/ChannelStream.cs then I wrapped the stream with a BufferedStream

In Android/Java there are no seekable streams (the ContentResolver is a part of Android and this limited to the capabilities of Android/Java). The maximum you can get is a buffered input stream which allows to "rewind" up to a certain number if bytes (the buffer size).

I managed to solve this by getting the Java Channel associated to the Stream and then calling Position() in a similar way to https://github.com/madnik7/PortableStorage/blob/master/PortableStorage.Android/ChannelStream.cs I then wrapped the stream with a BufferedStream
